# Paper buttons work correctly in firefox only

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm using Polymer and paper buttons from it to make my something like website material. After I load webcomponents, it looks exacly how it should in firefox only, and in chrome/ium it's to high. (all newest versions)

Chrome - win8.1 (shot using Browserstack, but chromium under linux looks like this too.
[image: chrome screenshot]

Firefox 30 - win8.1
[image: firefox screenshot]

I don't have access to IE, and in browserstack it seems that it misses loading of webcomponents to time when screenshot is took.

Source code: http://pastebin.com/impPE91t

Answer (score 0):

You *must* [explicitly specify](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#fouc-prevention) that `body` is *unresolved* on initial load (until Polymer took care about) to prevent [FOUC issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

So, instead of

```
<body>
```

use should use:

```
<body unresolved>
```

**UPD** And instead of

```
<style>
```

use should use:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
```

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/rXdcULMrxkVidn9ZXYfr?p=preview

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but the live preview works even if I remove that "unresolved". In iframe, I get the issue I'm seeking help for.

Comment: @hoschiCZ 1. Despite it works without `unresolved`, it’s _not guaranteed_ it would work without `unresolved`. 2. Would you shed the light on “... iframe ...” Do you experience problems in iframe? The code you provided contained no iframes. 3. Would you copy-paste the example I provided and run it locally? The problem is somewhere within your setup, since I cannot reproduce it with my bundle of browsers.

Comment: @hoschiCZ Please see an update. This actually should not affect Chrome, but it’s mandatory for polyfill as well. Since I’m unable to reproduce the described behaviour, I would suggest you to start with bringing your code to standards.

Comment: Copy-pasted your example, and same issue perists (with shim-shadowdom too). Both FF and Chromium. What do you mean by 'unable to reproduce'... You need to have included scripts in your bower_components directory.

Comment: I mean I don’t experience any problem with buttons height: everything is rendered fine. **Wait**; now you experience the problem in **both** Chrome **and Firefox**?

Comment: No. Just Chromium. Do you (or anybody else) have access to IE or even Spartan?